# Printing recursion in reverse order

Tags: java

This week assignment for my online CS1 course is to create a program that uses multiple methods to print a reversed triangle. I have created the methods as outlined by the professor, but find myself wholly stuck in printing the recursing in reverse order. At first I could not grasp recursion at all. It seemed like a For loop could do the same job with less abstraction. After more reading on the subject I feel like I have a better understanding as to how it works, not necessarily why its used. This is what I have right now:

```
public class RecursiveTriangle {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int sideLength = getLength();
        String trianglePattern = getPattern();

        printTriangle(sideLength, trianglePattern);

    }


    public static int getLength ()
    {
        Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in); 

        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int sideLength = scr.nextInt();

        return sideLength; 
    }

    public static String getPattern() 
    {
        Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
        String trianglePattern = scr.nextLine();

        return trianglePattern; 
    }

    public static void printTriangle(int sideLength, String trianglePattern)
    {
        if (sideLength < 1){return;}
        printTriangle(sideLength - 1, trianglePattern); 
        for (int i = 0; i < sideLength; i++)
        {
                System.out.print(trianglePattern);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

The current iteration prints out a triangle in the "normal" order. An input of int(5) and String ("AA") yields :

```
A
AA
AAA
AAAA
AAAAA
```

The final iteration of the program should yield :

```
AAAAA
AAAA
AAA
AA
A
```

I would appreciate some help here. Will gladly read/watch recommended material on recursion, as so far this is the first concept that I have found challenging.

Comment: What if you call the method `printTriangle(int sideLength, String trianglePattern)` *after* print the pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say your recursive method is simply counting down from `n`.

```
static void countDown(int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
        return;
    countDown(n - 1);
}
```

---

To print in *recursion order*, insert print statement *before* recursive call:

```
static void countDown(int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
        return;
    System.out.println(n);
    countDown(n - 1);
}
```

*Output*

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

See, a count down from 5.

---

To print in *reverse*, insert print statement *after* recursive call:

```
static void countDown(int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
        return;
    countDown(n - 1);
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

*Output*

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

See, counting up, i.e. the reverse of counting down.

Answer (score 1):

*In order to understand recursion, one must first understand recursion.*

The first thing to really understand recursion is that **it should not be difficult**. The use case of recursive approach the opposite: simplify problems.

Classic problems solved by recursion are the prime factorization, factorials, towers of Hanoi, etc. More related to CS can be data structures searching/order algorithms.

A good point to start is the following [freeCodeCamp article: "How recursion works - explained with flowcharts and a video"](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-recursion-works-explained-with-flowcharts-and-a-video-de61f40cb7f9/)

Regards!

PD: Sorry for go beyond the question itself, but it was already answered before with unbeatable concision.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Just reverse the order of the print statement and the recursive call in `printTriangle()`:

```java
    public static void printTriangle(int sideLength, String trianglePattern)
    {
        if (sideLength < 1){return;}
        for (int i = 0; i < sideLength; i++)
        {
                System.out.print(trianglePattern);
        }
        System.out.println();
        printTriangle(sideLength - 1, trianglePattern); 
    }
```

Tested in Java:

[image]